# "Divide the divided"?

Tags: expressions, translation

Is there a political hypothesis that has the same meaning as "dividing the divided"?

I've seen it in Arabic but didn't find the English equivalent. It's used in the context of countries. It is like "divide and rule" concept.

Comment: What should "deviding  the devided" mean?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You need to provide context or example sentence.

Comment: @Rathony It's related to politics. Let's suppose Country B is already divided into two main regions. Country A's intervention into Country B's affairs will only cause more divisions. The already divided A, will suffer from more divisions. That's the idea.

Comment: Please edit your question body with examples and write an example sentence where the phrase would be used. The following is the strict guideline of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term I would use is "subdivided." In political history, an example is dividing the former India into India and Pakistan, then *subdividing* Pakistan into Pakistan and Bangladesh.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
I later thought of "intra-divide". I wasn't sure about it but I think it works, right?

Comment: @Anomalisa: Yes it does.